Auto Hot Key stopped working after modifying a script
I need to remap certain keys so that CapsLock + "ijkl" would result in arrow keys without actually toggling CapsLock on.
Standard practice.
ChatGPT gave me the following code which worked as expected:
CapsLock:: 
    KeyWait, CapsLock  ; Wait until CapsLock is released
    return

#If GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")  ; Check if CapsLock is toggled on
i::
    Send, {Up}
    return
#If

Then I added more key mappings:
CapsLock:: 
    KeyWait, CapsLock  ; Wait until CapsLock is released
    return


#If GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")  ; Check if CapsLock is toggled on
i::
    Send, {Up}
    return
j::
    Send, {Left}
    return
k::
    Send, {Down}
    return
l::
    Send, {Right}
    return
#If

And now script runs and only prevents CapsLock from toggling on (seen from LED inactivity on keyboard).
Going back to initial code didn't change anything (still only blocking CapsLock)
I tried to launch script with double-click, to launch as administrator, to run with UI access
I did reboot the PC just in case :)
Since the initial code worked fine the first time I guess the problem isn't related to syntax but to some system settings.

The ChatGPT generated answer does not work as you describe.

The ChatGPT answer 1. rebinds "i" to "up" when capslock is ON; 2. disables capslock toggling when pressing capslock without modifier keys

Is this behavior what you actually want?

@Thomas, hello. As Shift key adds a layer with capitalized letters, I want CapsLock to be treated similarly. Combination CapsLock + i should result in Up, CapsLock + j => Left and etc. I just need to find a way to make CapsLock such a modifier, make it do nothing while if statement listens to its condition

I see now, so diabling the capslock press is unintended

A simple script like this would do:
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

capslock & i::Send "{up}"
capslock & j::Send "{left}"
capslock & k::Send "{down}"
capslock & l::Send "{right}"


Thanks a lot. I thought such combination would leave capslock on after moving the carriage. This technique will suffice by the time I feel I’m ready for vim motion

By the way I would strongly suggest switching to ALT instead of capslock, as it makes CTRL/SHIFT combinations easier to press, enabling text selection and word jump navigation. Also U and O can be bound to Home and End respectively.
